# Using $this in static context

Tags: php, stripe-payments

Just [downloaded a new version of Stripe API](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php) and PHPStorm editor detected an error [on this line.](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php/blob/master/lib/Stripe/Object.php#L152)

```
 public static function constructFrom($values, $apiKey=null)
  {

    $class = get_class($this); // <- accessing $this in static function.

    return self::scopedConstructFrom($class, $values, $apiKey);

  }
```

How is `$this` accessible in a static function? Is this a bug in their code?

Comment: $this is meaningless in a static method because it refers to an instance; but static methods don't have an instance... hence the message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug.

It produces an error notice ("Notice: Undefined variable: this") but works (outputs the class name as expected) in 5.3.1+, and doesn't work in versions below that.

They should have used [`get_called_class()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-called-class.php).

Output in various PHP versions: http://3v4l.org/HoW0U